# Feren OS wallpaper

Tags: linux, kde, wallpaper

I have just installed Feren OS 20 and I am trying to change the desktop wallpaper from the default to an image I've downloaded from the internet. I've looked all around settings and only managed to find out how to change the lock screen wallpaper. I am wondering if it is even possible to change the desktop wallpaper in Feren OS.

Answer (score 0):

Feren OS is based on KDE Plasma. To change the wallpaper on KDE Plasma, right click on the Desktop and choose the "Customize workspace" option (the place where this option is and how it is called differs depending on your version of Plasma). This should open up a window where you can adjust your wallpaper.